# SharePoint 2010-2013 Consolidate Weekly PowerPoint Slides

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powerpoint

Our team creates their own weekly slides to review activities and add them to one powerpoint file in a shared drive.

Can this process be simplified in SharePoint so a user can upload their slide(s) in a library and they be automatically placed in the appropriate weekly slideshow together?
I make 2 slides, you make 3 slides, he makes 1 slide.... and they put themselves in one powerpoint file.

This may not be the best way to approach it but I have to consider a better method for this process I've no doubt happens in many offices.

Comment: Please take a look on this article  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-together-on-powerpoint-presentations-0c30ee3f-8674-4f0e-97be-89cf2892a34d#OfficeVersion=2010

Comment: Thank you for sharing!